# Separating table column into 3 parts

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am having problems with dividing my bottom row into 3 parts. I would appreciate some help with this by fixing it or redesigning it.

Html:

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td style='width:120px; height:20px;'>Creeper</td>

        <td rowspan="2" style='width:120px; height:120px;'></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" style='width:100px;'>Creeper</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td style='width:120px; height:120px;'></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td style='width:40px; height:20px;'></td>

        <td style='width:80px; height:20px;'></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/j76bY/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your table like below.

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" style='width:120px; height:20px;'>Creeper</td>

    <td rowspan="2" style='width:120px; height:120px;'></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td rowspan="2" colspan="2" style='width:100px;'>Creeper</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td style='width:120px; height:120px;'></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td style='width:40px; height:20px;'></td>
    <td style='width:80px; height:20px;'></td>
    <td style='width:120px; height:20px;'></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/j76bY/3/)

Answer (score 0):

try this : http://jsfiddle.net/66ZSm/

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td colspan='3' style='width:120px; height:20px;'>Creeper</td>

        <td colspan='3' rowspan="2" style='width:120px; height:120px;'></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan='3' rowspan="2" style='width:100px;'>Creeper</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan='3' style='width:120px; height:120px;'></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan='2' style='width:40px; height:20px;'></td>
        <td colspan='2' style='width:40px; height:20px;'></td>
        <td colspan='2' style='width:40px; height:20px;'></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```